# can a paramter be added to an existing method of an existing class via javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I just need a simple example demonstrating addition of a parameter to an existing method of an existing class using javassist. As far as I have searched it seems to me that this is not possible and we would have to create a copy of the method which basically boils down to creating a new method via javassist. So please I want to know that whether this is even possible or not?

for example,Ii have a `Greetings` class:

```
public Class Greetings{
public void sayHello(String visitor)
{
System.out.println("hello"+ visitor)
}
}
```

Now I want to add another parameter to the `sayHello` method at runtime using javassist.

Comment: even if that is possible, what good would that do, seeing as you don't change the implementation?

Comment: @Stultuske i would change it based on the second parameter but i just want to be sure and get an idea of whether it can be done or not

Comment: as far as I know, you can't.

Comment: @Stultuske thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me should have jsut check the javassist docs first .They clearly mention that "Javassist does not allow to add an extra parameter to an existing method". Here is the link for anyone else stumbling upon this thread 
http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial2.html